# Bottle server not responding while calculating

Tags: python, bottle, gevent

I have a bottle server running on port 8080, using the "gevent" server. I use this server to support some simple "server sent events".

My question is probably related to not knowing exactly how my set up is working. I hope someone can take the time to elaborate on this.

All routes and serving of files from the server is working great, but I have an issue when accessing a specific route "/get_data". This gathers data from the web as well as from some internal data sources. The gathering takes about 30 minutes. While this process is running, I am not able to access any routes on the server, i.e. "/" or "/login". Once the process is finished, everything works again and the database is updated with the gathered information.

I tried replacing the gathering algorithms by a simple time.sleep(60), and while the timer was active, I was still able to access other routes just fine.

This leads to my two questions:

1. Why am I not able to access the server while this process is running. Is it the port that is blocked (from reading web-information), or maybe it has something to do with threading?
2. What would be the best way to run a demanding / long process on my server? Preferably I would like to access this from my web app, but I have thought about just putting this in a seperate python file and run this localy on the server, in a seperate instance of python. This process is run at most once per day, maybe as seldom as once per week.

Answer (score 3):

This happen because WSGI handle request/response synchronously.
You can use `gunicorn` to run your application, it will handle multi requests and response, or you can use other methods described in bottle website:
[Primer to Asynchronous Applications](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html)

Comment: I'm not completely sure how this applies. I am using the gevent server with monkey.patch_all(). As i wrote everything is fine when using the time.sleep(), so something must be right. Seems to me that the application can handle multi requests and responses, but something is causing the data-scraper to block everything.

Do i have to use the gevent.queue for this, or is gunicorn the only solution?